At what context does XBTGT4230 returned "Upload Editor Project fails"?
I must extract the editor project from XBTGT4230 through the "Upload" method. The problem is that the feedback zone of Vijeo-Frame kept returning "Upload Editor Project fails" ,so I want to know if the touchscreen program's author actually included their editor project or not.
What does "Upload Editor Project fails" mean?
